# While in while with readdir

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I have a list of projects and i have to show 3 img per project. My code:

```
$path = "works/";
$dont_show = Array("", "php", ".", "..");
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Error");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo '<li>
        <span>'.utf8_encode($row["client"]).'</span>
        <ol>';
            while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)){
                $pos = strrpos($file,".");
                $extension = substr($file, $pos);

                if (!in_array($extension, $dont_show)) {
                    echo '<li><img src="'.$path . $file.'" /></li>';
                }
            }

            closedir($dir_handle);
        echo '</ol>
    </li>';
}
```

So, Im trying to show my projects vertically and the images horizontally of each. But i cant find the solution, the second while isnt work... thanks and i apologize for my english.

Comment: Is this just a styling problem? If not, what's your PHP question? If you're just trying to get the images to show up horizontally instead of vertically, then you'd need to set the `<li>`'s to `display:inline`, e.g. you could give your `<ol>` an ID (`<ol id="myList">`) and then use the CSS `#myList li {display:inline;}`

Comment: The css is ok! The second while isnt working... thank you

Comment: You're closing the directory handle after the first iteration of the inner loop. Try moving `closedir($dir_handle);` after the end of the outer loop.

Comment: Oh, `readdir` doesn't go back to the first file after it reaches the last file in the given directory. So you'll need to either use `opendir` within your inner loop, or use `scandir` to store the directory contents in array ahead of time (not in any loop) and then loop over that.

Comment: (Sorry not to be more specific, I need to sign off...)

Comment: In such applications, i suggest you to use a 2-pass solution. Scan directories and prepare a data structure to represent files. Then use sprintf() like functions to fill your table templates.

Comment: why do you want to how the same images under different projects?

Comment: no, each project have differents images, like this: editorial/idbrand/ 01.jpg 02.jpg 03.jpg // graphic/idbrand/01.jpg 02.jpg etc

Comment: thanks matt and diego, I store in array the directories and then use a forloop into the while

Comment: Don't read the folder for every single row in your database. Read it once outside the loop and save it to an array, and then loop through the array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better do this:

```
<?php
    $path = "works/";
    $dont_show = array("", "php", ".", "..");
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Error");

    // Store the file list from folder (but only the accepted ones)
    $file_list = array();
    while (($file = readdir($dir_handle)) !== false) {
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (!in_array($ext, $dont_show)) array_push($file_list, $file);
    }
    closedir($dir_handle);

    // Now do your while loops
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
        echo "<li><span>" . utf8_encode($row['client']) . "</span><ol>";

        foreach ($file_list AS $file) { // Loop stored values
            echo "<li><img src=\"{$path}{$file}\" alt=\"\" /></li>";
        }

        echo "</ol>";
    }
?>
```

Note that using `echo "text {$variable} text"` is the same as using `echo "text " . $variable . " text"`.

Comment: i found two options, your solution and while into the global while (?) and pass $_get all id´s of the table with select * from.. and done! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason you are trying to show the files from **one single directory** all the time, while you apparently need different ones.

So, you have to move `opendir()` *inside* the loop, and create `$path` dynamically, every time for the corresponding project images directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
  /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

    }

    /* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

    }
```

Why? 
We are explicitly testing whether the return value is identical to FALSE since otherwise, any directory entry whose name evaluates to FALSE will stop the loop (e.g. a directory named "0").

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: Well said, but it still doesn't answer his/her question.

Comment: santyas has a problem in the second (while) loop. It would be nice if he lists the content of the directory. Anyway, the problem is not with the readdir() function, instead while() evaluates the return value to false. The probable reason here (given files exists in the directory) is one of(may be the first) the file name is evaluated to false. That's why its better to check using 'in value and in kind' comparison.